# How to extract values from Kriging interpolation

Tags: r, gstat

I can't extract ‘var1.pred’, ‘var1.var’ from the predicted values in kri, they are all shown as NA.

```
data=read.csv('D:/R/R程序/2016.12.31/对比气温数据/2016年均温.csv')
bound=readOGR('F:/ArcGis/RACGIS数据库/江苏省行政区/泰州.shp')
dsp <- SpatialPoints(rev(data[,1:2]), proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
dsp <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(dsp,data)  
WGS84<- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0")
dsp1<-spTransform(dsp,WGS84)
bound1<-spTransform(bound,WGS84)
blank_raster<-raster(nrow=150,ncol=150,extent(bound))
values(blank_raster)<-1
bound_raster<-rasterize(bound,blank_raster)
plot(bound_raster)
v=variogram(value~1,dsp)
m=fit.variogram(v,vgm(0.13,'Gau',150,2.2))
plot(v,m)
Grid<-as(bound_raster,"SpatialGridDataFrame")
kri<-krige(formula=value~1,model=m,locations=dsp,newdata=Grid,nmax=12, nmin=10)
spplot(kri['var1.var'],col.regions =rev(heat.colors(16)),do.log = TRUE,scales=list(draw = TRUE),main=list(label="克里金标准差",cex=1.2,fontfamily="song"))
```

I can use spplot to draw a heat map for kri, but I can't extract the predicted values in kri, such as ‘var1.pred’, ‘var1.var’, they are all shown as NA.
[https://pan.baidu.com/s/12IF2ZNWf4a9-idZpw2jYWw]  Extraction code：3kch

```
head(kri)
      var1.pred var1.var
    1        NA       NA
    2        NA       NA
    3        NA       NA
    4        NA       NA
    5        NA       NA
    6        NA       NA
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF1Bg.png)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data so we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I added a file in the question, which contains two files. One is the site data stored in .csv, and the other is the boundary data shp.

Comment: You should not provide files, but data generated by code, or data that comes with R. See all the examples in the R help files. You need to do the hard work of asking a good question (minimal and reproducible). Here are some examples that may help you with interpolation of spatial data: https://rspatial.org/analysis/4-interpolation.html